# jQuery, DataTables, ajax error handling: get rid of "Processing" message

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatable

I am using jQuery DataTables, ajax and Bootstrap in a small project.  It is mostly working and I am testing error states.  I have setup my html for the DataTables table.  There is a `table-responsive` div surrounding the `<table>`.

```
<div id="errorDiv"></div>
    <div id="resultTableDiv" class="table-responsive">
        <table id="resultTable"  class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>...</th>
                ...
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>...</th>
                ...
            </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the DataTables init I setup the ajax call and specify an `error` callback function.  This "works" in that I can force an error in the server side ajax code and the callback is fired.  I can handle the returned error as I want.

My issue is that when the ajax call starts the table body is "replaced" by a `Processing` message. That's fine except that when ajax reports the error via the callback the processing message is still there and I have yet to figure out how to make it go away via the DataTables methods or API calls.

my error callback looks like

```
function ajaxError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
    if (obj && obj.Error) {
        $('#errorDiv').html("<p>" + obj.Error + "</p>");
    }
}
```

I have a "global" variable that holds the DataTables table definition.  It is set in the jQuery ready function

```
var table;
$(function () {
    $('#errorDiv').empty();
    $('#resultTable').show();

    table = $('#resultTable').DataTable({
        paging: false,
        processing: true,
        autoWidth: false,
        ordering: false,
        ajax: {
            url: "ions.cgi",
            dataType: 'json',
            dataSrc: "LIST",
            error: ajaxError
        }, ...
```

In the error callback I have tried all of the following:

```
table.clear().draw();    // does nothing
table.fnRedraw();        // says that function does not exist
```

In this error state how should the `Processing` message be reset?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The element which shows the processing message gets the id `<idOfTable>_processing`, so you could hide it using:

```
$('#resultTable_processing').hide();
```

This might have changed, and the id could be different, but the concept stands, you can just find out how to identify the element and hide it. DataTables will show it again if it has to.

Also, do you want the processing message showing up in other ocassions? Because you can just make it never appear by using `processing: false` on the DataTable's options (or just not setting it at all, since it's the default behaviour not to show it).

Comment: Hmm, I assumed there would be an API call that I was missing.  I do see the named processing div but hiding it seems a bit hacky. I'm not saying it is not the answer just that it feels inelegant when there is all that other API functionality. However, it works and thank you

Comment: It is a bit hacky but the [alternative](https://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/api/fnProcessingIndicator) offers no benefit and is a plugin. [Here](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/7325/processing-notice-and-ajax-error-handling) you can read an explanation on why it remains open.

Comment: This works in DataTables 1.10.11. The element id still consists of `[table-name]_processing`

Comment: `processing: false` do the magic